# Explaining Resnet50/Densenet121 outputs with LIME

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, visualization

I am trying to explain the outputs of my Transfer learning models in Keras with LIME. I am following this [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/interpreting-image-classification-model-with-lime-1e7064a2f2e5).

My model is a multi-class image classifier. I am implementing LIME on my resnet50 mode. There are 4 classes in the dataset.
the code snippet of LIME:

```
img = cv2.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/Dataset/cat/cat129.png')
img = cv2.resize(img, (224,224))
img = image.img_to_array(img)
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)

import lime
from lime import lime_image


explainer = lime_image.LimeImageExplainer()


img[0].shape

explanation = explainer.explain_instance(img[0].astype('double'), model.predict,  
                                         top_labels=3, hide_color=0, num_samples=1000)
from skimage.segmentation import mark_boundaries

temp_1, mask_1 = explanation.get_image_and_mask(explanation.top_labels[0], positive_only=True ,negative_only=False, num_features=5, hide_rest=True)
temp_2, mask_2 = explanation.get_image_and_mask(explanation.top_labels[0], positive_only=False ,negative_only=True, num_features=10, hide_rest=False)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15,15))
ax1.imshow(mark_boundaries(temp_1, mask_1))
ax2.imshow(mark_boundaries(temp_2, mask_2))
ax1.axis('off')
ax2.axis('off')
```

The output I expecting was something like this: [image]

But the output I'm getting is something like this: [image]

I want to know how I can achieve this, which line of code should I modify?

Comment: I suspect that the output of LIME is a "heat map" of the explanation only. If so, you have to plot the image and the output on the same figure.

Comment: @Minh-LongLuu i followed this link: https://towardsdatascience.com/interpreting-image-classification-model-with-lime-1e7064a2f2e5 .
The output of this link doesn't match with mine.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to **rescale** the test image before fitting into the model. You need to add the below code also for rescaling the image while preprocessing image to get the desired result.

(Attaching the replicated [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/5e2566134cc4a16be604e974f373c018/75306453.ipynb) here for your reference.)

```
img = cv2.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/Dataset/cat/cat129.png')
img = cv2.resize(img, (224,224))
img = image.img_to_array(img)
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
img = img / 255.0  # rescaling image
```

Output:
[image]